# Breathing technique when doing the across bench dumbbell pull over to minimize injury and maximize hypertrophy

Tags: dumbbells

Follow up to [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/46316/38114), I'd like to ask how are we supposed to breath when doing this exercise?

Normally when there is a chest related movement, we have to do the valsalva maneveur but I heard that the major point of this exercise is to get the maximum extension, and for thhat, it was mentioned in one answer to breath out. See [discussion here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/45954/why-do-we-exhale-before-doing-reps-in-ab-exercises).

Hence, which is correct?

Comment: I think you’re thinking about these things the wrong way. “Correct vs incorrect” is rarely a helpful way to think about things like this. You haven’t given us any criteria for what is correct to you, and there is no objective standard for doing pullovers. So asking what way is correct doesnt make any sense at all. Instead, ask about the outcome you’re interested in. What are you trying to do, and why? Then, if you think your breathing pattern might have some material affect on that outcome, ask about it, and if you don’t think it will affect the outcome, then it probably doesn’t matter.

Comment: @ThomasMarkovwasonStrike My correctness is simple: Injury minimization and with maximum muscle group activation.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing at the discussion states. Tighter core inhaled, more spine flexion, exhale. You will be bracing more by doing it across the bench instead of flat on it, therefore requiring more stability.. so Inhale and tense like you’re bracing for a deadlift.